# How to do conditionally something in rxjs pipe?

Tags: angular, rxjs

Could somebody tell me what is the right syntax for an rxjs pipe with a conditional operation?
In this case i would like to do the mapping with the filter, if the enviroment name array lenght is not  1. How can i use an if statement without return? Is there any rxjs operator for this?

```
environmentName = ['env1', 'env2'];

sourceList$ = this.getSources().pipe(
tap((srcList) => console.log(srcList)), //[["stylesheet","env1-xyz"],["include","cable"],...]
// if(this.environmentName.length!==1){
map((sourceList) => sourceList.filter((scr) => scr[1].startsWith(this.environmentName[0]) || scr[0] === 'include')),
//}
repeatWhen(() => this.sourceListChanged$)
);
```

Comment: Thank you, i'm really new to angular.

Comment: Is there any reason why you would not build your if statement our of the pipe? if (...) {pipe A} else {pipe B} ?

Comment: `iif` https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/iif and `filter` https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/filter could both be used for this task

Comment: @mikegross How can i handle that here?
<editor-sidebar-item
      *ngFor="let source of editorService.sourceList$ | async | sourceIsInclude: false"
      [value]="source.join('/')"
      type="stylesheet"
      (delete)="handleDelete(source)"
      (upload)="handleUpload(source)"
    >
    </editor-sidebar-item>

Comment: @BEVR1337 I tried these operators. Probably in a wrong way.  Could you share the syntax in this case?

Comment: @DavidGregor Yeah I could slap together an answer. Your code has some commented out logic so it's hard for me to see exactly what you're trying to accomplish with conditional logic. Could you please share some psuedo code in the question that shows the desired behavior? It's fine if the code is broken.

Comment: @BEVR1337 https://codepen.io/gregi1991/pen/GRvazBP

Comment: Wow, that's a lot of code! I don't know which part to look at first. Can you please share some psuedo code, or a trimmed down example, or a higher-level example?

Comment: @DavidGregor seems to me like your filter is correct on line 26, but you're checking the wrong length. Your array has a length of 2, not 1.

Comment: @BEVR1337 Sorry, a trimmed it.  I want the filter the sourceList if there is only one enviromentName. I want to pass all the data if it's different from 1

Comment: with that ´filter(() => this.environmentName.length === 1)´  i don't get back anything, if my array is longer than 1

Comment: @DavidGregor I just added an answer. Your issue boils down to returning the opposite value you want to filter. Please comment on the answer if I can provide any more clarifying details. Good luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mentioned `iif` is not operator. Use e.g. `mergeMap` to incorporate it into your code:

```
environmentName = ['env1', 'env2'];

const filterSourceListByEnv1OrInclude = srcList => srcList.filter((scr) => scr[1].startsWith(this.environmentName[0]) || scr[0] === 'include');

sourceList$ = this.getSources().pipe(
  tap((srcList) => console.log(srcList)),
  mergeMap(srcList => iff(
    () => this.environmentName.length !== 1,
    of(filterSourceListByEnv1OrInclude(srcList)),
    of(srcList)
  )),
  repeatWhen(() => this.sourceListChanged$)
);
```

Or ternary operator could be used instead of `iif`:

```
sourceList$ = this.getSources().pipe(
  tap((srcList) => console.log(srcList)),
  mergeMap(srcList => of(this.environmentName.length !== 1
    ? filterSourceListByEnv1OrInclude(srcList)
    : srcList
  )),
  repeatWhen(() => this.sourceListChanged$)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

> Could somebody tell me what is the right syntax for an rxjs pipe with a conditional operation?

If client software is already piping from a source, [`filter`](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/filter) is a tool that provides a quick solution. Returning `true` from filter will continue the pipe. Returning `false` will drop the value from the pipe. Returning false does not affect the underlying subscription.

```js
const source$ = /* snip */;
source$.pipe(
  filter((v) => v % 2 === 0) // non-even values do not continue
  tap((v) => {
    console.log("Even value received: ", v);
  })
).subscribe(
  /* snip */
)
```

If a new source is desired, then [`iif`](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/iif) is suitable.

```js
iif(
  () => someCondition, // if someCondition
  () => sourceA$, // then return sourceA
  () => sourceB$, // else return sourceB
).pipe(
  /* pipe the source returned from `iif` */
).subscribe(
  /* subscribe to the source returned from `iif` */
)
```

Based on your example, the condition you want to check is whether an array has a length of 1 (false) or not (true).

> if the enviroment name array lenght is not 1

I've adapted your code on [CodePen](https://codepen.io/gregi1991/pen/GRvazBP) to make sense as a standalone example, here is an example:

```js
const environmentName = ['env1', 'env2'];
sourceList$.pipe(
  tap((sourceList) => console.log("Source list: ", sourceList)),
  filter(() => environmentName.length !== 1)
).subscribe(
  /* snip */
);
```

Your code fails because you are performing the opposite check. In your example, the pipe will continue only if the length IS 1. Since the array is hard-coded and has a length of 2, the filter will never pass.

Comment: i couldn't make it working. But probably i'm dead tired. I will mark your answer as soon i clear my mind.

Comment: @DavidGregor You're very close to a solution, I promise! The obvious issue is you returned the opposite boolean value you wanted. There could be other issues cropping up as race conditions because you're filtering based on a value in lexical scope but it's not being observed inside RxJS. Feel free to @ me tomorrow and I can continue to help add clarification to the answer

Comment: Thank you for your effort. I couldnt use your solution in this case, propably because i'm novice. I used the mergeMap with a funcion. Your answer is also good, i'm sure..