# Is there another way of having an IF statement inside nested subscriptions using RxJS?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I need to assess the result of the first observable to determine if the second one should be subscribed to. From reading other threads and the RxJS documentation I can see that nested subscriptions should be avoided where possible. Below is an example:

```
    obs1().subscribe(result=> {
      if (result.status === 'success') {
        obs2().subscribe(() => {
          executeMethod();
        });
      }
    });
```

Any help or resources are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hello, you might find some answers here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70084666/how-to-do-conditionally-something-in-rxjs-pipe. This will be better for your code if you start using rxjs operators instead of `subscribe()`. Chhers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could look like this:

```
obs1().pipe(
    filter(result => result.status === 'success'),
    switchMap(() =>  obs2()),
).subscribe( //...
```

Comment: That's done the job perfectly, thank you!